# A set which is closed under addition and is well-ordered

Tags: abstract-algebra

If I have a set of objects which support + and <, is that necessarily isomorphic to  a subset of the real numbers?

I ask this question because I'm trying to figure out the most general type of a parameter in a Scala program I'm writing.  The only thing I assume about the type is that it supports addition and ordering.  I.e., given two of them, `a` and `b`, I need `a+b` to be in the type; and given any two of them, `a` and `b`, I need to be able to evaluate `(a < b)` to make an if/then decision.  Someone suggested, that this is just the set of what Scala calls `Numbers`.  My first reaction was, no that's too restrictive, but then I can't think of any other example.

Comment: [No, as there are ordered fields of every infinite cardinality.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1099986/are-there-fields-and-ordered-fields-of-every-infinite-cardinality)

Comment: I figured out a way to answer the question without answering it.   It turns out I don't really need `<`, what I need is `+` and `if (a < b) then a else b`.   And I can generalize those two operations to the operations of a semi-ring.    E.g., the positive integers with operation + and min. 

Although that does not answer my original question, it does solve the programming problem which motivated the question.